# what would have been

Tags: conditional-constructions

In an email I received, the professor wrote:

> I am trying to decide how best to proceed with our content for this week. For now, I will post slides for **what would have been today's lecture** by this afternoon.

I thought the structure **would have been** is associated with the past (conditionals and modals). Then why did she use this structure in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Her statement is associated with the past.

Something has happened which caused her to not take an action (presumably teaching your class.) As a result of this occurrence, she is still going to post the slides which she planned to use for your lecture.

Comment: Oh, so it does refer to the past. But I still don't understand. Because when I received the email, the class hadn't even started yet. So it seems "future" to me.